# ExoPlayer - Player is accessed on the wrong thread with RxJava2

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, rx-kotlin

From past developers, I got a large `library`, which is built on the basis of `ExoPlayer`, which allows you to listen to audio books.

Everything worked fine until the `library` itself had to update the version of `ExoPlayer` to a newer one (this was very important)

In short: there is a small interface that has a `ProgressBar` showing how many seconds the audio has already been playing. Here is the code for this:

```
private lateinit var mExoPlayer : ExoPlayer

private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
private val currentTrackProgress = MutableLiveData<Long>()

private var currentTrackProgressDisposable : Disposable? = null
private val playbackProgressObservable : Observable<Long> =
    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map {
        mExoPlayer.currentPosition
    }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

////////////////////// So many code here
////////////////////// Somewhere there is a call to the "createExoPlayer()" function

private fun createExoPlayer() {
    mExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()

    mExoPlayer.addListener(object : Player.Listener {

        override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying : Boolean) {
            if (isPlaying) {
                currentTrackProgressDisposable = playbackProgressObservable.subscribeBy(
                    onError = { error ->
                        Log.d("error", error.toString())
                    },
                    onNext = { progress ->
                        currentTrackProgress.value = progress
                    }
                )
                compositeDisposable.add(currentTrackProgressDisposable!!)
            }
        }
    })

    mExoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
}
```

Before updating `ExoPlayer` version, everything worked fine, but after updating to the latest version, an error began to appear in `onError`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Player is accessed on the wrong thread.
Current thread: 'RxComputationThreadPool-1'
Expected thread: 'main'
```

What could be the reason for this and how to fix it? After all, I didn’t even update the `RxJava2` version, but only updated `ExoPlayer`

Comment: My guess, `mExoPlayer.currentPosition` is now restricted. Use `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` and drop `observeOn`.

Comment: Any Update hier

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you, this fixes my issue. You should post this as an answer.